# Java - ( Apache POI ) Setting Cell Formula within a Loop

Tags: java, apache-poi, spreadsheet

[image: Scenario]

Hello Java Developers,

Here's a straight question. How would I be able to set the Cell's formula within a loop in Apache POI? 
Here's an information to support my question:

**Illustration 1**: Cell C1 has the formula of `SUM(C6:C7)` which can be done by simply hard coding the formula `myCell.setCellFormula("SUM(C6:C7)")`.
On the other hand:

**Illustration 2**: This is my desired output. I want to set a formula on Cells `C1, D1, and E1` for example. How can this be done within a loop?
Why would I want it within a loop?
- Hard-coding would be tiresome. 3 cells are just and example. Currently I have hundreds of cells waiting for their formula.
- Row count are not specified, it will be based on the number of rows created by the program.

What I have done?
- Googled.
- Searched for similar question.
- Apache POI's column is represented by an Integer (Number of cells within a row).

The formula requires Alpha C2 (Column C, Row 2). I tried to loop through the Spreadsheet and realized that if I continue, the formula will result to `SUM(26:27)` (Where: 2 = Column C, and Row 6(Base 1: rowCount + 1) which I want to be `SUM(C6:C7)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have finally solved the problem.
`CellReference.convertNumToColString(myColumnNumber)` will return the column name

Answer (score 1):

What have you tried so far (code)?

Try something like this (but you have to put more thought into it when you get past column Z:

```
  int col=2;
  int row=6;
  char ccol = (char) (('A'+col)&0xff);
  String formula=String.format("SUM(%c%d:%c%d)", ccol, row, ccol, row+1);
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll try to reconstruct my loop.